# History.go(-1) not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a go back button and i have used the following piece of code in my aspx page

`<input type="button" runat="server" value="Back" onclick="Javascript:history.go(-1); return=false;" />`

The prob is its working fine in Firefox but when i am trying it in IE its not working. Can someone share their Idea.

### Update

By mistake I write `return=false;` the actually code is:

`<input type="button" runat="server" value="Back" onclick="Javascript:history.go(-1); return false;" />` and still not working.

Comment: Which version of IE are you having this problem?

Comment: There is no reason to use the javascript label in the click events.

Comment: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: @ChristopherBales i am usung IE 8

Comment: You can not change that way the question because then the answer can not be understand. Its better to write that you have write it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that there is pages on history to go back ?

Comment: @Aristos , yes, because its working fine in firefox, but not in IE

Comment: @user1658567 The go back, using javascript is not good programming user interface anyway. Do you get any error on console ? Do you have try it with other simple javascript code ? Do you see the back arrow on ie8 active and working ? Do you use UpdatePanel maybe ?

Answer (score 7):

Your quoted code shouldn't be working on any browser, it has a syntax error (`return=false`). With minimal changes:

```
<input type="button" runat="server" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" />
```

Also note that you don't need (and shouldn't have) any `Javascript:` prefix on any `onXyz` attribute. The code in `onXyz` attributes is **always** JavaScript, and in fact that prefix (in that situation) doesn't trigger JavaScript, it creates a [label](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12) that's never used. You use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in places where a link is expected, such as the `href` attribute on an `a` element.

Side note: I haven't done any `ASP.Net` in a long time, I'm not at all sure it makes sense to have `runat=server` and `onclick` on the same `input`... If you want a client-side "Back" button, remove `runat=server`.

Comment: By mistake i have written `return=false;`.I used the same code u have suggested but still its not working in IE but working in firefox ...

Comment: @user1658567: Did you try removing the `runat="server"`? Because the above (without `runat="server"`) works just fine in IE: http://jsbin.com/asuxiz/1

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a href="Javascript:history.go(-1); return false;">Back</a>`
or
`<input type="button" runat="server" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" />`

After any `on...` events you need no `javascript`, you need it only at `href`.
And at the `return` you need no `=`.